# yii2-httpclient with Basic Auth and proxy settings

Tags: yii, proxy, yii2, basic-authentication

in my Yii2 application, I try to read data from an REST api, which is protected by an HTTP-Basic - Auth. Additional, a proxy is needed to connet the REST api.
So I chose the Yii httpclient-module to handle this call:

```
$client = new Client(['baseUrl' => 'http://my.example.com']);
$response = $client->createRequest()
        ->setMethod('get')
        ->setUrl('api/session')
        ->addHeaders(['Authorization' => 'Basic '.base64_encode("user:password")])
        ->setOptions([
            'proxy' => 'proxy.server:8000',
            'timeout' => 5, 
        ]);
```

Running this code, I get an `Bad URL in proxy request` error-message form the Server.
But if I copy the URL from code to the browser (which also connected to the proxy), everything works fine: the Basic-Auth window comes up.

Is there an error in setting the `Authorization`  tag for the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working a day on this problem, in found the answer. Just a minute after asking my question, but I like to keep that question in the case, that someone has the same problem.

Answer:
The yii2 httpclient uses 2 different transport libraries: [Streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) (which wokrs without an additional PHP extension and is set as default) and cURL.

Switching to cURL as "transport-type", the code above works fine!

```
$this->client = new Client([
            'baseUrl' => 'http://my.example.com',
            'transport' => 'yii\httpclient\CurlTransport'])
```